# Best place to add polyfills to Object in Chrome Extension

Tags: google-chrome-extension

I am working to add the Object watch polyfill by Eli Grey through a Chrome Extension. The script should be executed before any page gets parsed. When the javascript files or inline scripts get executed, I am looking to watch cookie property of document object.

Here is what I tried:

manifest.json

```
{
  "manifest_version": 2,
  "name": "Cookie Tracker",
  "description": "Tracks cookie",
  "version": "1.0",
  "browser_action": {
    "default_icon": "icon.png",
    "default_popup": "popup.html",
    "default_title": "Click here"
  },
  "background": {
    "scripts": ["scripts/object-watch.js", "myScript.js"]
  },
  "content_scripts" : [{
    "matches" : ["http://*/*", "https://*/*"],
    "run_at": "document_start",
    "js": ["scripts/object-watch.js", "myScript.js"]
  }],
  "web_accessible_resources": ["scripts/object-watch.js"]
}
```

myScript.js

```
document.watch('cookie', function(id, oldValue, newValue) {
  console.log("document.cookie oldValue-",oldValue, " newValue-", newValue);
});

console.log("myScript executed");
```

scripts/object-watch.js

Content from  -- https://gist.githubusercontent.com/eligrey/384583/raw/96dd5cd2fd6b752aa3ec0630a003e7a920313d1a/object-watch.js

I tried both content-script and background-pages. When I load the extension from directory and load the page. I only see in my browser console:

```
>Object-watch executed
>myScript triggered
```

I do not see the changes to document object's cookie property when I load any page though the page is setting cookie's. I am not sure what I am missing? Can someone provide some hints.

Comment: To access page context of `document`:  [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](//stackoverflow.com/q/9515704) and revisit the [extensions overview: architecture](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/overview#arch) because only content scripts can access a webpage.

Comment: Are you sure the cookies are set through the page's JS? They may be httponly cookies and/or set by the server.

Comment: If your exact purpose is just watching cookie changes, don't ignore the [`chrome.cookies`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/cookies#event-onChanged) API.